# How to create RowVersion column for optimistic concurrency using model first approach?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx, ef-model-first, optimistic-concurrency

I am working on a legacy web app which implements model first(edmx file) approach using Entity Framework.

I need to implement optimistic concurrency, so I have added this field as following:

[image]

and inside the database has been created as **binary(8)** type.
But when I try to update the entity is getting updated but the VersionRow values is not updated(no new value generated).

P.S

When I added the column I have binded default value as 0x0000000000000000 because it does not allow null values.

Answer (score 2):

Yea I solved it this way:

1) I changed the type of RowVersion column from Binary(10) into timestamp inside SqlServer.

2) In the property details inside the .edmx file I have put the property **StoreGeneratedPattern** of the property RowVersion as **Computed**.

```
Computed it means that a new value is generated on insert and update.
```

Now it became as following:

[image]